# SQL Server 2008: Creating dynamic Synonyms?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

in my SQL Server 2008 database I have a number of different tables with the same structure. I query them in different stored procedures. My first try was to pass the table name to the stored procedure, like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTest
  @tableName nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM @tableName
END
```

But we can't use parameters for table names in SQL. [So I asked you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789413/sql-statement-with-dynamic-table-names-or-redesign) and tried the solution with using Synonyms instead of a parameter for the table name:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTest
  @tableName nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
  EXEC SetSimilarityTableNameSynonym @tbl = @tableName;
  SELECT * FROM dbo.CurrentSimilarityTable
END
```

SetSimilarityTableNameSynonym is a SP to set the Synonym dbo.CurrentSimilarityTable to the passed value (the specific table name). It looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetSimilarityTableNameSynonym] 
@tbl nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
  IF object_id('dbo.CurrentSimilarityTable', 'SN') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP SYNONYM CurrentSimilarityTable;

  -- Set the synonym for each existing table
  IF @tbl = 'byArticle'
    CREATE SYNONYM dbo.CurrentSimilarityTable FOR dbo.similarity_byArticle;

  ...
END
```

Now, as you probably see, the problem is with concurrent access to the SPs which will "destroy" each others assigned synonym. So I tried to create dynamic synonyms for each single SP-call with a GUID via NewID()

```
DECLARE @theGUID uniqueidentifier;
SET @theGUID=NEWID()
SET @theSynonym = 'dbo.SimTabSyn_' + CONVERT(nvarchar(255), @theGUID);
```

BUT ... I can't use the dynamical created name to create a synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM @theSynonym FOR dbo.similarity_byArticle;
```

doesn't work.

Has anybody an idea, how to get dynamical synonyms running? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: How many such tables (with identical structure) do you have?

Comment: 5 at the moment (some more are possible). Each one contains ~15 mill entries. The largest table has 29 mill entries.

Answer (score 1):

All I can suggest is to run the CREATE SYNONYM in dynamic SQL. And this also means your code is running at quite high rights (`db_owner` or `ddl_admin`). You may need `EXECUTE AS OWNER` to allow it when you secure the code.

And how many synonyms will you end up with for the same table? If you have to do it this way, I'd use OBJECT_ID not NEWID and test first so you have one synonym per table.

But if you have one synonym per table then why not use the table name...?

What is the point is there creating 1 or more synonyms for the same table, given the table names are already unique...

I'd fix the database design.

Comment: I'd need a synonym for each request, not for each table. When accessing the SPs concurrently, they would otherwise change the synonym while the other SP still needs it.

Comment: @aaginor: but why not just use the table name dynamically, rather than creating synonyms?

Comment: As far as I know, execution plans and caching doesn't work with dynamic sql. Anyway, this is a solution possibility I'll probably have a closer look at.

Comment: @aaginor: everything executed in SQL Server has a plan. The engine will try to re-use a plan.

Comment: hm, think I will try dynamic sql with sp_executesql. Thanks for the infos!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want multiple concurrent users to overwrite the single resource (synonym)?
If your MyTest procedure is taking a the table name as a parameter, why not simply do dynamic SQL? You can validate the @tableName against against a hardcoded list of tables that this procedure is allowed to select from, or against sys.tables